# file was built for arm64 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am building a framework first to use in my ios simulator. However I get  this error when importing it into the main project:

> file was built for arm64 which is not the architecture being linked
>   (x86_64)

Here is the build info of my framework:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I created a universal framework using this technique: https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c but I'm still getting the error

**UPDATE:** Results from running file on the binary:

```
hunterp$ file dinkle 
dinkle: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
dinkle (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
dinkle (for architecture arm64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library
```

Comment: <strike>when building the framework, did you choose "Build Active Architecture Only = NO" ? Most people forget this.</strike>

Comment: @Raptor look at the image....that answers your question does it not?

Comment: oops, my bad, I over-looked it.

Comment: Can you show the output of running `file` on the binary?

Comment: OK, can you double check that "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to no for all configurations? E.g. expand the menu from the triangle on the side.

Comment: @danielbeard Updated image in description

Comment: Can you show the build log entry that Xcode outputs for the linking step of your build?

Comment: I was using an old binary.....

Comment: Give a try ---->>> In **Linking**  Section under **build Settings**, Change `Mach-O Type` to `Static Library`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was incorrectly copying the binary framework and using an old one from before I changed it into a universal.

Comment: Did you worked with LIPO? 
If you want to get your framework to work with simulator and with real devices too you'll have to do that. :)

Comment: actually i would like to know how you created a universal framework. since i tried to create one using lipo -create but no success. i followed many tutorials with no success. thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

To create framework and convert .h file into .a fat file. Compile your project with simulator target and device target ,after these two tasks you have to join to make universal file with shell.